# How to use Postman and the FIWARE API?

Tags: fiware

Some of the tutorials of the FIWARE Wednesday Webinars e.g. this one https://youtu.be/SP0zFdTybA4, show the use of Postman to interact with the FIWARE API. I am not sure what configuration needed to get it up and running.

I could use the curl command but when run the postman. I am new to both FIWARE API and Postman.

Can anyone show me how to configure Postman to use with FIWARE API? Thanks.

Comment: I came across this YouTube video, "IoTphile. FIWARE. An european initiative for the future Internet II", https://youtu.be/p8Rmr25iUyg, where at 
3:25' it demonstrate the use of RESTClient tool for mozilla firefox browser add-on. To me, that may be the same idea for Postman although I don't intent to try it out as yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Install Postman
2. Check out one of the [Tutorials](https://fiware-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting-started/index.html)
3. At the top of the Tutorial, there is the option "Run in Postman"
4. Postman will open and you will see the collection e.g. "FIWARE Getting started" [image: Posttman collection]
5. If you Fiware system runs at a different server than localhost, e.g. example.com you need to modify the variable `{{orion}}` in the collection
6. Click on the three dots at the collection, then choose Edit and in the Variables tab overwrite Current value with your server address.

Answer (score 1):

1. Install and launch Postman.
2. Change the request operation as required(POST, GET, APPEND, etc).
3. Enter the public IP Address of required node, with full path.
   For example:

   - In case of POST request to iotagent-json: `http://<Ip Address>:7896/iot/json?i=<deviceID>&k=<api-key>`
   - In case of GET request from Orion context-broker: `http://<Ip Address>:1026/v2/entities`
4. Add headers(-H) in `Headers` tab:

   - Add `fiware-service`, `fiware-servicepath`, `content-type` and its values.
   - Default value of `fiware-service` is `openiot` and `fiware-servicepath` is `/`.
5. If request type is POST, add data payload in `Body` tab, also choose `aplication/json` as content type from the dropdown menu.
6. Send to hit the given API.

**One can also import CURL request statement in Postman:**

1. Open Postman Application
2. Click Import, located on top-left corner
3. From Import, select tab “Paste Raw Text”
4. Copy  and paste the CURL request data to the given input area below “Paste Raw Text” tab.
5. Click Import located at the bottom-right
6. Check whether data type is `application/json` or not in body tab, if not select 
   `application/json` from the drop-down menu in body tab.
7. Click “Send” button to post the data."

For more detail, refer to my config:

1. [POST Request on iotagent-json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKwCc.png)
2. [GET Request from Orion context broker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1JR5.png)